# CollectionReference to DocumentReference

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to perform a firestore transaction in Flutter.
Therefore I need to pass the `documentReference`.

There is no problem, when accessing the "lesson" document based on the identifier.
The issue is when fetching the active user pass. The `where` I'm trying to use returns the `Query`, and the `.reference()` returns the `CollectionReference` (which is not accepted by the transaction method).

How can I get the reference to the document basing on the value of its field.

To spice it up: DB rules don't allow me to read ALL the passes. I've got only access to those, that have my UserID (double checked - working).

```
  DocumentReference lessonRef =
    await _db.collection('lessons').document(lesson.identifier);

  CollectionReference passRef = await _db
        .collection('passes')
        .where('userID', isEqualTo: user.identifier).reference();
```

[image: DB structure]

Answer (score -1):

You can get the DocumentReference of the Queried documents like so:

```
Firestore.instance
.collection('passes')
.where('userID', isEqualTo: user.identifier)
.snapshots()
.listen((reference) =>
    data.documents.forEach((doc) => /*do what you want with doc.reference*/));
```

(I'm not an expert in Flutter and I could't test the code, but I based the answer in [the API reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html))